# Visual Studio 2017 Xamarin Android API Level 25: Enable the default proguard

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio

I cannot build my android application with the default visual studio 2017 proguard enabled.

I enable the proguard from

**Project > Android.Properties > Android Options > Check "Enable ProGuard"**

Then I cannot build my application.

It says:

> C:\Program Files (Access is denied)

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

This was a [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=32861) in xamarin.
happens if the android sdk path contains space ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk").
You have to move the android-sdk to a path without spaces.(C:\android-sdk)
See [here](https://xamarinsharp.com/2017/02/19/how-to-fix-error-cprogram-files-access-is-denied-when-proguard-has-enabled-while-build-a-android-app/) how.

*This was reportedly fixed so upgrading Xamarin should fix the bug however note that some devs reported as of 2017-06-22 that this was still reproducable using:*

> Xamarin 4.6.0.267 (750994b)
>   Xamarin.Android SDK   7.4.0.9 (5f3167a)

So if the updating all the tools and sdk does not work you will have to move the directory as described above.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following I had a similar issue and work for me:
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn java.nio.**
-dontwarn java.lang.invoke.**
The conversation about the same issue was continued here with other solutions:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/45210/enable-proguard-error-c-program-files-access-is-denied

Answer (score 1):

it's a common Linux/Windows command-line compatibility issue. you might have to set `ANDROID_HOME` (the path to the Android SDK, without spaces) under "System Properties" > "Advanced System Settings" > "Environment Variables" > "System Variables". Visual Studio should pick up these values - also check permissions on `proguard.exe`, eg. if the current user can run it from the command line. here it's also explained: "[How to Fix Error “C:\Program Files (Access is Denied)” When Proguard has Enabled while Build a Android app](https://xamarinsharp.com/2017/02/19/how-to-fix-error-cprogram-files-access-is-denied-when-proguard-has-enabled-while-build-a-android-app/)" (linking the SDK is the other option). Moving the whole SDK to `C:\Android\SDK` might be suggested. Visual Studio may even install the SDK twice, when installing it beside an existing IDE, unless one has `JAVA_HOME`, `ANDROID_HOME` and `ANDROID_AVD_HOME` (the emulator images) defined. Having the SDK within the user profile (or within "Program Files") is rather problematic. At least, these variables can be used to change the individual install locations (in order to fix `PATH` issues alike this - or to delete eventual duplicate SDK installs).